# mysql_query is memory freed when local variable no longer exists?

Tags: php, mysql, memory-management

When using mysql_query inside of a class method and setting it to a local variable is memory freed when the method finishes execution or at the end of the script? Is it worth adding `mysql_free_result`? Below is example.

```
class example{
    public function Query($query){
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $this->rows[] =$row;
        }
    }
}
```

Will memory be freed when the method finishes or is it necessary to call `mysql_free_result` at the end of the method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `mysql_` php functions are not maintained anymore and thus you may want to use a more `OOP` approach such as [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) functions.

Since `mysql_free_result()`

> will free all memory associated with the result identifier result.

If you are fetching a lot of results then yes, you can (and should) use this function to free your mysql to save memory.

As for the rest of your question:

> Will memory be freed when the method finishes or is it necessary to call mysql_free_result at the end of the method?

No, in case of you are not using the `mysql_free_result` the memory won't be freed at the end of your method but rather in the end of the execution of your script.

I hope it helped. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It's an ORM class, eventually I need to move to mysqli or pdo but it should be easy enough to change in one spot.

Comment: If an answer is correct, please mark it as so. Otherwise Stackoverflow will never know that your problem has been solved. Consider to upvote answers that are somewhat helpful, doing so other users with similar question can find answers with more ease.